# Pyspark-Jupyter- Docker : How to rebuild and deploy image/container after defining master and worker node in the jupyter/pyspark-notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, microservices

How to rebuild the jupyter-pyspark-notebook docker container after add/modify the script in it?

My requirement is as follows after pulled the jupyter/pyspark-notebook

1. Create a Master and worker node in the cluster as 2 container 1 for master and for worker
2. Build a image/container as docker containerization application
3. Deploy this container as microservices application

I am not seeing any suitable article or document specifically related to this..

Appreciate if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the [blog article](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-do-i-create-a-new-docker-image-for-my-application/).

1. Pull `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` and run
2. Do your modification
3. Commit the custom docker image to the docker hub by 'docker commit'. To do this, you might be needed to log-in to the docker hub.
4. Check your custom image from the docker hub
5. Pull your docker image from your application

Comment: Hi Lamanus, thanks for your replay.. however how can define the master or worker node in the docker?

Comment: You don't. This is standalone.

Comment: so you mean to say this image can only work for stand alone not a master or worker node?

Comment: If you deployed a cluster first and then you can use this image as a client to connect the cluster by setting the spark session, but this image itself is not for the cluster.